# Can't import mymodule in Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode and getting warning "search is not accessed in Pylance" when trying to import my own module, search is the name of the module I need to import to my main program

[image]

1- I do have `__init__.py` file on module folder

2- Tried changing interpreter

Importing mymodule as below:
`from src import search`

folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

Could the reason of this be that 'src' is being treated as a module instead of a folder?

[image]

Is there an alternative way to import my modules?

Thanks

Comment: You aren't showing your file structure, so it's hard to help. `from src` is an antipattern and implies you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `"search" is not accessed` means you are not using `search`,

[image]

If you use `search` below then this error will go away.

[image]